# Running gunicorn for HTTPS by using a public certificate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gunicorn, uwsgi, aws-certificate-manager

I need to run a flask HTTPS API application by using either Gunicorn or uWSGI. I have acquired a public certificate from AWS (ACM or AWS Certificate Manager) so It doesn't have any chain certificate files. Based on the gunicorn documents to run an HHTPS application, the syntax is like below

> gunicorn --certfile=server.crt --keyfile=server.key test:app

But to my underestanding I do not have such such certifcate files like above server.crt and server.key as I have aquired a public certifcate from ACM in AWS.

Can I run gunicron with such a public certifcate?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run gunicron with such a public certifcate?

No. Certificates from ACM can't be exported and you can't use them with `gunicron`. You have to get valid certificates from an external party, such as https://letsencrypt.org/.